# Will any Shimano V brake fit any v brake lever and any v brake bike?

Tags: compatibility, rim-brake

I need to replace the V brake on [this](https://www.giant-bicycles.com/en-gb/bikes/model/2014.liv.giant.escape.3.w.mint/15015/66796/#specifications) bike:
[image]

It uses Shimano EZ FIRE 40 brake levers, and has Shimano V brakes installed (Tektro TK837).

Can I replace these V brakes with any other V brakes available on the market (E.g. [Shimano Deore BR-T780 XT V-brake](http://www.halfords.com/cycling/bike-parts/bike-brakes/shimano-deore-br-t780-xt-v-brake)), or are there compatibility issues to consider?

More generally, if a bike already has V brakes installed and working, can I just go ahead and fit any V brakes I find without having to worry about whether they will fit?

Comment: Yes it should be compatible'

Comment: While the levers are compatible with the brakes some align better with Revo-style shifters than Rapid-Fires and vice-versa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they all work together. Only exception is all mini V-brakes. They are not compatible with standard V-brakes.

Comment: Does this mean mini V-brakes are for standard road brake levers?

Comment: Yes, more or less. I had a set of mini-V's that didn't work well with Campagnolo levers, I gave them to a co-worker who has Shimanos and they work much better on his bike.

Answer (score 3):

I installed the brakes and they were compatible, though the rear brakes didn't fit as snugly as the originals; note the gap between the brakes and the frame:

[image]

But it all works fine regardless.

Comment: Is the bolt too long? Would a shorter bolt eliminate the gap? Or could you insert a washer as a spacer? As an engineer, I don't like gaps - they put strain on the bolt.

Comment: @RoboKaren Yeah I think the bolt was too long, though I can't confirm as I don't have the original bolts anymore. I think I might need quite a big washer to remove that gap!